# Dúvida para exibição na view

Tags: laravel

Boa Noite, estou tentando puxar o conteúdo do meu banco ordenado pelo campo created_at, mas na view não aparece nada, não dá erro, mas não aparece nada do banco por outro lado.

**Código no HomeController**:

```
public function index()

{
    $postagens = Postagens::orderBy('created_at','desc');
    return view('index', compact('postagens'));
}
```

**Código na view**:

```
@foreach ($postagens as $pubs)
   @postagens()
      @slot('titulo')
         {{$pubs->nomePost}}
      @endslot

      @slot('descricao')
         {{$pubs->descricao}}
      @endslot

      @slot('nome')
         {{$pubs->usuario}}
      @endslot

      @slot('dia')
         {{$pubs->created_at}}
      @endslot

      @slot('id')
         {{$pubs->id}}
      @endslot        
   @endpostagens
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma

```
public function index()
{
    $postagens = Postagens::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
    return view('index', compact('postagens'));
}
```

No seu código faltou o método get().

Veja a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results).

Comment: Estranho que não ta aparecendo de forma decrescente ainda, ta imprimindo em ordem de inserção no banco.

Comment: Tente isso: dd(Postagens::toSql()) e veja como está query gerada pelo Laravel.